# pcap: how to check for packet boundaries in pcap_dispatch

Tags: linux, network-programming, pcap, libpcap

I'm using `libpcap` to process PCAP files, find IP header, extract something, move to udp/tcp and extract something and so on.

`pcap_dispatch()` punts the packet to a callback defined as:

```
typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes);
```

If I'm reading the man-page correctly, `bytes` above is a *pointer* to `caplen` bytes of data from the packet, where `caplen` is in `struct pcap_pkthdr *`.

Does it mean, that `pcap_handler` routine would need to maintain the end of packet buffer pointer, and always check before moving `bytes` pointer along?

Alternatively, I would just allocate buffer inside of `pcap_handler`:

```
u_char *pktbuf = malloc(h->caplen);
```

and it would guarantee the boundaries.

What is normally the right way of processing pcaps within `pcap_dispatch()` or `pcap_loop()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`bytes` is guaranteed to be at least `h->caplen` big. Other than that, you don't need to do bound checks.

Comment: thanks for comment. However, if you're trying to access IP packet inside the PCAP buffer it is possible you go beyond the buffer boundary (for example, due to bug in the code).

Comment: That's why I say "other than that". If you keep to the promised `h->caplen`, you'll be fine. If you don't, you're looking for trouble.